# Rspec2 Rails3 rake spec fails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, show, rspec2

I can run my tests by just running parts of my code via RubyMine (rightklick into _spec.rb file and run). But, by running "rake spec" I get an error. The table is removed and not rebuilt bevore each test. I know it makes sence, but not if it's not rebuilt again.
Things like db:test:load, db:test:prepare, db:test:clone_sturcture also don't work.When i just run "rake spec" I get this errors:

```
C:\RubyStack\ruby\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\RubyStack\ruby\bin\rake spec
Testing started at 14:11 ...
(in E:/idun/ComServer_v0.0/source)
C:/RubyStack/ruby/bin/ruby.exe -S bundle exec rspec ./spec/controllers/customer_controller_spec.rb
Empty test suite.

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'comserver_test.customers' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `customers`
C:/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:207:in `rescue in log'
C:/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:199:in `log'
C:/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:314:in `execute'
C:/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:288:in `update_sql'
C:/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:331:in `update_sql'
C:/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:293:in `delete_sql'
C:/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:54:in `delete'
C:/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:16:in `delete'
C:/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/arel-2.0.9/lib/arel/crud.rb:34:in `delete'
C:/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/relation.rb:273:in `delete_all'
C:in `delete_all'
E:/idun/ComServer_v0.0/source/spec/controllers/customer_controller_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
```

*_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'customer'
require 'rack/test'
require 'rspec'
require 'logger'

RSpec.configure do |conf|
  conf.include Rack::Test::Methods
end

def app
  Rails::Application
end

describe "customers" do

  render_views

  before(:each) do
    Customer.delete_all
  end

  describe "GET on /customers/:id" do
    before(:each) do
      Customer.create(
        :gmsid => 1,
        :online => true,
        :pinged_at => DateTime.now
      )
    end

    it "should return a customer by id" do
      @response = get("/customers/1")
      @response.status.should eq(200)
      attributes = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@response.body)
      attributes['customer']["online"].should be_true
    end

    it "should return \"null\" if customer not found" do
      @response = get('/customers/2')
      @response.body.to_s.should eq("null")
    end
  end

  describe "should POST on /customers" do
    it "should create a user" do
      customer =  Customer.new(
        :gmsid => 2,
        :online => false,
        :pinged_at => DateTime.now
      )
      puts customer
      json = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(customer)
      @response = post('/customers', json)
      @response.status.should eq(200)
      @response = get('/customers/2')
      attributes = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@response.body)
      attributes['customer']['gmsid'].should eq(2)
      attributes['customer']['online'].should be_false
    end
  end

  describe "should PUT on /customers/:id" do
     before(:each) do
      Customer.create(
        :gmsid => 1,
        :online => false,
        :pinged_at => DateTime.now
      )
    end

    it "should update a user to status true" do
      @response = put('/customers/1', ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(Customer.new(
          :online => true
      )))
      @response.status.should eq(200)
      @response = get('/customers/1')
      attributes = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@response.body)
      attributes['customer']['online'].should be_true

    end

    it "when user doesn't exist should return null" do
      @response = put('/customers/2', ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(Customer.new(
          :online => true
      )))
      @response.status.should eq(200)
      @response.body.to_s.should eq("null")
    end
  end

  describe "should DELETE on /customers/:id" do
    it "should delete a existing user" do
      Customer.create(
          :gmsid => 1,
          :online => true,
          :pinged_at => DateTime.now
      )
      @response = get('/customers/1')
      #test if customer with gmsid 1 is in database
      @response.status.should eq(200)
      attributes = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@response.body)
      attributes['customer']['gmsid'].should eq(1)
      #delete customer with gmsid 1
      @response = delete ('/customers/1')
      @response.status.should eq(200)
      #check if customer with gmsid 1 is not in database anymore
      @response = get ('/customers/1')
      @response.status.should eq(200)
      @response.body.to_s.should eq("null")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it's db:test:prepare which is invoket by doing "rake spec". If I run it manually it simply destroys my tables!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem.

It was the "libmysql.dll problem" discussed [here](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues#issue/71).

Problem is the mysql 5.0 Version. It should be higher than 5.1. So, I just changed the "libmysql.dll" to one from a newer mysql version. It worked. 
You need this to create a proper dump from your development environment (db:schema:dump).
This command creates a schema.rb in your project.
This schema is used by "db:test:prepare", which is invoked everytime when executing "rake spec", before testing. This schema.rb was empty, so no tables habe been created. 
Sounds logically to me.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.